# How to get rid of this video flickering?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, hdmi, screen, troubleshooting

When connecting my RasPio to my tv (rather old, but not tube tv anymore), I get [this weird flickering](https://i.imgur.com/Gkqv3kR.gifv) everywhere on the screen where clean, thin lines with big contrast are present (including fonts). I already tried increasing `config_hdmi_boost` in `/boot/config.txt` up to eleven, but I'm getting no visible change. I know that my cable as well as my television are able to display clear lines as I'm using both with another device that works perfectly.

Can someone tell me how to solve this, or at least name me the problem? 
I'm using raspbian on the Raspberry Pi 3 Model M.

Comment: I've removed the Youtube link. It wasn't helpful.

Comment: *"I already tried increasing config_hdmi_boost in /boot/config.txt up to eleven"* -> Probably a bad idea; [the maximum recommended is 7](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#config_hdmi_boost).  Unfortunately someone somewhere at some point indicated it was possible to set this higher, but I am pretty sure someone also ended here reporting having set it progressively higher (all the way to 11) and wondering why their HDMI output no longer worked for anything, period.

Comment: A+ video. Laughed way too hard, considering it relates to the question.

Comment: Anyways, try blowing on the sockets. Try getting a known-good cable. Maybe it's your TV, try on another monitor.

Comment: @goobering Ah, no? Since you can't identify the problem? I think "flicker" can be interpreted in many ways - try google

Comment: @goldilocks Hmmm, but it flickered even  before I began changing the config file, and it still works with the other device. I think it's not the cable.

Comment: @PandaLion98 Thanks a lot for your contribution, but if you read the question again (carefully), you will see that your suggestions wont change anything.

Comment: @Nearoo My comment had nothing to do with the cable.  My point was, the manufacturer has recommended you do not exceed `config_hdmi_boost=7`, and if it "flickered even before [you] changed the the config file", then it implies you've exceeded this out of ignorance (which is understandable, the documentation is not necessarily easy to find) as a sort of throw-darts-blindly-and-wildly, and since this *may* have caused someone else's HMDI controller to *eventually* die completely, you may want to throw that dart a little less wildly.  I don't have a solution, I am just *warning* you of something.

Comment: @goldilocks I misunderstood you then, thanks. I have read somewhere `config_hdmi_boost` is to be used "at your own risk", so I only used it for a very short time. But most of the time, noone tells you anything about what it does and if it's dangerous.

Comment: Yes, I am much more impressed by the official product than the official effort to document it ;) Did you try `hdmi_safe=1`, BTW?  That link in my first comment is fairly thorough WRT that stuff if you [scroll up a bit](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi-mode-options).  If you can't get things to work out using that information, and if you can test the pi on another HDMI display to make sure that it isn't damaged or defective, then you may just be out of luck with that combination :(

Comment: @goldilocks Alright. I read through the documentation. Tried stuff out for about an hour, and now it works! I had to change the hdmi_mode. By default, my screen wanted interlaced footage, but displayed it with blinking - changing it to progressive did do the trick. Had to write my own mode and painfully adjust the overscan settings, but it works _perfectly_ now. Many thanks for your patience!

Comment: Great. If you have time to provide the exact answer to your own question please do so.  You then have to wait 24 hours to tick it if you want, but it may at least provide someone else a hint in the right direction at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that my TV-monitor displays interlaced footage really badly, even though it communicated to the Pi that it is able to support it.

Whether or not the video output by the Pi is interlaced or not is defined by the "HDMI-mode" set in `/boot/config.txt`. The mode defines attributes such as fps, screen_resolution or interlaced/progressive. Usually, the best mode is selected automatically, but in this case, I had to overwrite it manually.

Generally, not all possible modes are supported by a monitor. Entering `/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA` into the command line will list all possible modes. I selected the best possible mode (highest fps & resolution) that was not progressive and wrote its corresponding number into the `config.txt` as the `hdmi_mode` and then rebooted the system. More information about what possible values that flag can have and how to write your very own HDMI-mode can be found [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt/video.md).